# Need help solving the ODF $ f''(r) + \frac{1}{r}f'(r) = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently taking complex analysis, and this homework question has a part that requires the solution to a differential equation. I took ODE over 4 years ago, so my skills are very rusty. The equation I derived is this:

$$ f''(r) + \frac{1}{r}f'(r) = 0 $$

I made this substitution: $ v(r) = f'(r) $ to get get:

$$ v'(r) + \frac{1}{r}v(r) = 0 \implies \frac{dv}{dr} = - \frac{v}{r} \implies \frac{dv}{v} = - \frac{dr}{r} $$

Unsure of what to do now.

Edit: I forgot to add that the answer is $ a \log r + b $

Comment: Integrate: $\log v = - \log r + C$ so that $v(r) = \dfrac ar$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: I understand the integration, but how do you go from $ \log v = - \log r + C $ to $ v(r) = \frac{a}{r} $. That is the main problem I've been having.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. $ \log v + \log r = C \implies \log(v \cdot r) = C \implies v \cdot r = e^C = a \implies v(r) = \frac{a}{r} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this (which gets to the required form quicker in my opinion) is noticing that

$$ f''(r) + \frac{1}{r}f'(r) = 0 \implies \frac{1}{r}\left(r f'(r)\right)'=0$$

$$ \implies r f'(r) = c$$

$$ \implies  f'(r) = \frac{c}{r}$$
$$ \implies  f(r) = c \log(r) + d$$

where $c$ and $d$ are arbitary constants.

Answer (score 0):

You now have:

1/v dv = -1/r dr

We can integrate this:

ln(v) = -ln(r) + C1

v = e^(-ln(r) + c1)

v = 1/r + c1

Thus we have:

df/dr = 1/r + c1 (since v = f'(r) = df/dr)

df = (1/r + c1) dr

f = ln(r) + c1(r) + c2

And thats our answer!